# Did Anthony Scaramucci receive a certificate of divestiture in 2017?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, cabinet

I have read the following account of possible leveraging financial effects for [Anthony Scaramucci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Scaramucci) from joining the White House staff (briefly) in 2017. This is from Michael Wolff's new book *Fire and Fury: Inside the Trump White House*.

> While he wanted a job with the Trump administration, the Mooch
>   specifically wanted one of the jobs that would give him a tax break on
>   the sale of his business. A federal program provides for deferred
>   payment of capital gains in the event of a sale of property to meet
>   ethical requirements. Scaramucci needed a job that would get him a
>   "certificate of divestiture", which is what an envious Scaramucci knew
>   Gary Cohn had received for the sale of his Goldman stock.

Are there public (preferable Internet-accessible) records available that make it clear whether Scaramucci was in fact able to divest on these special terms despite a very brief tenure (10 days only, if memory serves)?

Comment: Would the tax be deferred for more than the ten days?

Comment: @DJohnM I wouldn't know. Please consider it part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to [USA today reporting](https://usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2017/08/03/anthony-scaramuccis-white-house-job-could-cost-him-7-million/531376001/) (emphasis is mine):

> WASHINGTON — Anthony Scaramucci took no salary during his short tenure as White House communication director — yet his 10-day career detour could end up presenting him with a tax bill of $12 million or more.
>
> That's because **the New York hedge fund founder left the White House before he could obtain a "certificate of divestiture"** giving him the special tax treatment available to federal employees who give up assets in order to avoid conflicts of interest.